# How to read Data from Url in python using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read the text data from the Url mentioned in the code. But it throws an error:

> ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 4, saw 2

```
url="https://cdn.upgrad.com/UpGrad/temp/d934844e-5182-4b58-b896-4ba2a499aa57/companies.txt"
c=pd.read_csv(url, encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there was some encoding issues with df.read_csv() it never splitted the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = "https://cdn.upgrad.com/UpGrad/temp/d934844e-5182-4b58-b896-4ba2a499aa57/companies.txt"
r = requests.get(url)
df = None
if r.status_code == 200: 
    rows  = r.text.split('\r\n')
    header = rows[0].split('\t')
    data = []
    for n in range(1, len(rows)):
        cols = rows[n].split('\t')
        data.append(cols)
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=header, data=data)
else:
    print("error: unable to load {}".format(url))
    sys.exit(-1)
print(df.shape)
print(df.head(2))

    $ ./test.py
(66369, 10)
                permalink      name            homepage_url                                      category_list     status country_code state_code      region           city  founded_at
0     /Organization/-Fame     #fame      http://livfame.com                                              Media  operating          IND         16      Mumbai         Mumbai
1  /Organization/-Qounter  :Qounter  http://www.qounter.com  Application Platforms|Real Time|Social Network...  operating          USA         DE  DE - Other  Delaware City  04-09-2014
```

Comment: getting error  "ValueError: stat: path too long for Windows"