# Error Reading csv file using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I seem to be having an issue reading a csv file that is comma delimited but has line breaks.  I have searched a lot on stack overflow using many different options with "pd.read_csv" but cannot seem to fix it.  I have messed with various forms of header, sep, engine, names, escapechar and quotechar and have had no luck reading in the file.

Below is my code with the accompanying error, I also downloaded the file I am trying to get to manually and posted a screenshot.  You can see that the file is comma delimited which should be the default but also has some odd line breaks.

**Code**

```
from requests import Session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

#log in to the website and navigate to the desired letting page
with Session() as s:
    site = s.get("https://www.bidx.com/")
    bs_content = bs(site.content, "html.parser")
    token = bs_content.find("input", {"name": "csrftoken"})["value"]
    login_data = {"username": "****", "****": "****", "csrftoken": token}
    s.post("https://www.bidx.com/", login_data)
    home_page = s.get("https://www.bidx.com/va/letting?lettingid=210324") #This currently directs the browser to the 2.24.2021 letting page
    print(home_page.content)
    print("Successful Login with CSRF")
    print(token)

    # ---------------------------------------------------EDIT THE Save Location--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    url = 'https://www.bidx.com/nc.div/letting?lettingid=L210324B&amp;action=exportcsv'
    path = "C:/Users/james/OneDrive/Pictures/Desktop/NCDOT/March 2021/tester.csv"
    df = pd.read_csv(url)
    df.to_csv(path)
```

**Error:**

```
Successful Login with CSRF
09950119ef7cbc419e7ec4eb01886abda5c6e9a4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/james/PycharmProjects/workingfiles/Vulcan/NCDOT/BidXNCDOT.py", line 20, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv(url)
  File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 676, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 454, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1133, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2037, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 859, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 874, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 928, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 915, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 2070, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 34, saw 3
```

And when I manually download the file and open it with notepad it opens in this form with the apparent line breaks (I did not add any breaks).

**Notepad Paste:**

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read Data from Url in python using Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54404465/how-to-read-data-from-url-in-python-using-pandas)

Comment: Thank you for posting the link, I appreciate it but I can't figure out what the solution was there.